# Как добавить свой ресурс в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Почему когда я добавляю новый .xml ресурс в папку res своего проекта, в классе R не регистрируется новый источник? Например если в res я добавлю table.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="tab1">column 1</string>
</resources>
```

То я не могу получить доступ через

```
R.table.tab1
```

даже после синхронизации

Answer (score 5, accepted):

после первой точки идет тип ресурса. Вы обьявили ваш ресурс как

`<string name="tab1">column 1</string>` (string). Чтобы получить к нему доступ, обращайтесь к нему, как к String Ресурсу: `R.string.tab1`

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю нет возможности добавлять кастомные типы ресурсов. В вашем случае придется воспользоватся папкой string